# Is there a term for the position of a phoneme in a word?

Tags: phonology

I am studying emerging Brazilian Portuguese consonant clusters and I'm unaware of how to properly call a group of positions such as "word-initial" or "word-final position". The aim is to use this term as an explanatory variable. I've thought about "segmental position" or "grammatical environment" but I'm still unsure about their appropriateness.

Comment: I guess "(consonant) phonotactics" is too broad a term for what you want?

Answer (score 3):

I've heard "phonological environment" for this sort of thing: it covers not just "word-initial" and "word-final" but also "between vowels", "word-final after back vowels", and so on.